# writing a spotify info command for my discord bot in python using discord.py, I dont receive any error when running command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def spotify(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    member = member or ctx.message.author
    for activity in member.activities:
        if isinstance(activity, Spotify):
            await ctx.channel.send(f"{member.display_name} is listening to {activity.title} by {activity.artist}")
```

this is the command's code, I just can't seem to figure out why it doesn't send the string after running. The only error I get is when I supply a member name that is not in the guild (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

After looking around I realized that since I am on discord.py 1.5.x I have to enable privileged intents for my bot to look at certain data, after enabling through the developer portal and adding the lines

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix =config['Prefix'] , intents=intents)
```

my code worked as intended.